# Scala Slick Play framework: How to join multiple DB tables using slick 3.x?

Tags: sql, scala, playframework, slick

I am working on scala play framework application and I need to fetch data from 4 tables. I don't know how to write join queries using slick ORM. I want to convert following query into slick query:

```
select r.id, r.resource_name, r.uri from resource r 
inner join resource_role r_role on r.id=r_role.resource_id
inner join role ro on ro.id=r_role.role_id 
inner join user_role users_r on ro.id=users_r.role_id
inner join users u on u.user_id=users_r.user_id where u.user_id='1sdf23sfd45dsf6....';
```

Or may be like if I can write native sql query using slick.

My mapped entities are as follows:

```
class ResourceTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Resource](tag, "RESOURCE") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def resourceName = column[String]("RESOURCE_NAME")
    def uri = column[String]("URI")

    def * = (id, resourceName, uri) <>
      (Resource.tupled, Resource.unapply _)
  }

  val resourceData = TableQuery[ResourceTable]

  class RoleTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Role](tag, "ROLE") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def roleName = column[String]("ROLE_NAME")

    def * = (id, roleName) <>
      (Role.tupled, Role.unapply _)
  }

  val roleData = TableQuery[RoleTable]

  class UserRoleTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRole](tag, "USER_ROLE") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def userId = column[String]("USER_ID")
    def userName = column[String]("USER_NAME")
    def roleId = column[Int]("ROLE_ID")

    def * = (id, userId, userName, roleId) <>
      (UserRole.tupled, UserRole.unapply _)

    def userFk = foreignKey("USER_FK", userId, usersData)(user => user.userID)

    def roleFk = foreignKey("ROLE_FK_1", roleId, roleData)(role => role.id)
  }

  val userRoleData = TableQuery[UserRoleTable]

  class ResourceRoleTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ResourceRole](tag, "RESOURCE_ROLE") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def resourceId = column[Int]("RESOURCE_ID")
    def roleId = column[Int]("ROLE_ID")

    def * = (id, resourceId, roleId) <>
      (ResourceRole.tupled, ResourceRole.unapply _)

    def resourceFk = foreignKey("RESOURCE_FK", resourceId, resourceData)(resource => resource.id)

    def roleFk = foreignKey("ROLE_FK_2", roleId, roleData)(role => role.id)
  }

  val resourceRoleData = TableQuery[ResourceRoleTable]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you seen https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#joining-and-zipping ?

Comment: and which slick version are you using?

Comment: play-slick - 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#joining-and-zipping) it would be something like:

```
val joined = for {
  r <- resourceData
  r_role <- resourceRoleData if r.id === r_role.resourceId
  ro <- roleData if r_role.roleId === ro.id
  ...
} yield (r, r_role, ro, users_r, u)
joined.filter {
  case (r, r_role, ro, users_r, u) =>
    u.userId === '1sdf23sfd45dsf6....'
}.map {
  case (r, r_role, ro, users_r, u) =>
    (r.id, r.resourceName, r.uri)
}
```

Comment: How to project result into `Resource` entity?

Comment: https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html#querying - after `.result` use `.map`

Comment: Can you please update the answer with mapping as I am getting some compile time errors while mapping result?